# How can i use multiples values for a@Assert\EqualTo Validation Field Entity

Tags: validation, symfony, annotations, entity, assert

I'm using *Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert* For validate the value of a field.

Problem is I need to accept two o more values for this field of my entity.

```
/**
 * @var integer
 * @Assert\EqualTo(
 *     value=1,
 *     message="Invalid State",
 *     groups={"Update"}
 * )
 * @Column(name="pgsStatus", type="integer")
 */
private $status;
```

It works perfect, but i tried something like this

```
/**
 * @var integer
 * @Assert\EqualTo(
 *     value={1,11},
 *     message="Invalid State",
 *     groups={"Update"}
 * )
 * @Column(name="pgsStatus", type="integer")
 */
private $status;
```

or this

```
/**
 * @var integer
 * @Assert\EqualTo(
 *     value=1,
 *     message="Invalid State",
 *     groups={"Update"}
 * )
 * @Assert\EqualTo(
 *     value=11,
 *     message="Invalid State",
 *     groups={"Update"}
 * )
 * @Column(name="pgsStatus", type="integer")
 */
private $status;
```

And doesn't work.
I've looked in documentation and I don't find another validation or another way for doing this.

Thanks!!

Comment: you can use [custom validation constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Choice Validator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Choice.html) is the way to go here:

```php
/**
 * @var integer
 * @Assert\Choice(
 *     choices={1,11},
 *     groups={"Update"}
 * )
 * @Column(name="pgsStatus", type="integer")
 */
```

Comment: Thank you...!!
I didn't tried this because I thought doesn't apply to my type field. So noob :(

Comment: gee, I think I gave the same answer first. :-(

Comment: @craigh In my timeline appears first this answer, and further he specified code solution. 
your answers is good too, I can't put a vote, but you deserve earn reputation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

probably use the [Choice](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Choice.html) validator or use the [Callback](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) validator